# Show default content in a template if an object is nil otherwise show based on the set property

Tags: go, go-templates

In my template, I would like to include some default `meta` tags (90% of the time). However, when a specific property is set, I would like to show a different set of text.

I know I can set an anonymous `struct` and set a property with either `"default"` or `"some-x"`. However, this means, I need to add an anonymous struct to 90% of my handlers that just currently pass `nil`.

Is there way to do something like

```
{{if eq . nil}} 
   // default meta tag
{{else if eq .MetaValue "some-x"}} 
   //other
{{end}}
```

If I try something like my above code, it compiles but doesn't do what I want. Appreciate any suggestions on how to handle  it properly without adding a lot of boiler plate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
{{if not .}}
   output when . is nil or otherwise empty including
     false, 0, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero
{{else if eq .MetaValue "some-x"}}
       // some-x case
{{else}} 
       // other case
{{end}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bravada. One related question: is it possible to check the existence of a `defined template`. If I have partials defined in each template (say "title") and I want to check the existence of it, there is no way to do that I presume? i.e., the pipeline can only come from the go handler?

Comment: There's no point in checking for the existence of the template. If you have {{template "title"}} in a template, then Execute will return an error if {{define "title"}}{{end}} is missing from the set of templates.

Comment: Got it. I was trying to do some default html insertions in case a template was not defined (like each partial may have an additional footer). If it is not defined, I wanted to skip it and if it is there, include it.  I ended up just making every page provide the same template definitions but blank values where appropriate.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to ensure you're only checking against `nil` and not `0`, `false`, the empty string, or any other falsey type, you can use [the `kindIs` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/reflection.html#kind-functions) to accomplish this.

```
{{ if kindIs "invalid" . }} 
   // only if variable is literally nil. falsey values will fallthrough.
{{ else if eq .MetaValue "some-x" }} 
   // other
{{ else }}
   // final case, if any
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Be warned that `kindIs` is only available if you are pulling in the [sprig functions](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig)

Answer (score 5):

I've been recently facing an issue with identifying nil vs 0 values in a Helm Chart (which uses Go templates, including [sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig)) and haven't found any solutions posted, so I thought I'd add mine here.

I came up with a kind of ugly solution which is to quote the value and then check for a string that matches "<nil>" (with quotes, so you'd actually be checking (quote .Values.thing | eq "\"<nil>\"")). This allows differentiating tests against empty values vs defined 0 values. In my case, I was trying to build a config file where some default options were non-0, so when 0 was explicitly set, I wanted to know that 0 was set instead of just omitted.

Hopefully this can be a help to someone else.

It would be nice to have a better way to do this, but so far I haven't found anything that doesn't require creating and adding my own template functions.

Comment: I didn't see quote function in golang templates, so with your idea, I checked for `if html .Page.Thing.Stationary | eq "&lt;nil&gt;"` and that worked!

Comment: Yeah that works too. The quote function exists in the [sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig) template library.

Comment: This no longer works in later versions of tiller (verified against 2.14.0). It now renders `(quote nil)` as an empty string (without quotes!).

What still works is `(typeOf nil)`, which renders as `<nil>` (without quotes), and works back at least in tiller 2.8.2, and continues to work up to 2.14.0.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly check for `nil` and not empty values like (`false`, `""`, `0` etc.) you can also use the `eq` function in `html/template`:

```golang
{{if (eq . nil)}}
   // include only if . is nil
{{else if eq .MetaValue "some-x"}}
       // include if . is `some-x case`
{{else}} 
       // everything else
{{end}}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://go.dev/play/p/yZrFt-sBfLJ)

I needed this for templating boolean values where `if not .` would trigger if the pointer was `nil` **and** if the pointer derefenced to `false`.