# How can I prevent non-nil values triggering a golang template if nil block

Tags: templates, go

The following is incorrectly showing "null" for values of `0`, but I only want it to do that for exactly `nil`.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type thing struct {
    Value interface{}
}

func main() {
    tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Parse("{{if .Value }} {{.Value}} {{else}} [null] {{end}}\n")
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: "hi"}) // outputs hi
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: nil})  // outputs [null]
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: 0})    // outputs [null] - should output 0
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: 2})    // outputs 2
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/Gg8uBCOb2vE

How do I make it show the value of `0` instead?

`.Value` is an `interface{}` which in the problem case contains an `int`, but could contain anything.

[Show default content in a template if an object is nil otherwise show based on the set property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774234/show-default-content-in-a-template-if-an-object-is-nil-otherwise-show-based-on-t) is close but not quite the same thing

Comment: Could always define a custom func for nil checking: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template_func

Comment: What. Is the Go type of .Value?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't know how you execute that template, nor what you pass for `.Value`.

Comment: .Value is interface{} which is pulled from the db, so can be of any type

Comment: I'll create an example

Comment: done, with playground. also my if was backwards, fixed. let me know if that's enough info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create a function that you pass to the template using `template.Funcs`:

https://play.golang.org/p/anxW5ooGE7N

```
funcs := make(map[string]interface{})
funcs["isNotNull"] = func(t interface{}) bool {
    return t != nil
}
tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Funcs(funcs).Parse("{{if isNotNull .Value }} {{.Value}} {{else}}[null] {{end}}\n")
tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: "hi"}) // outputs hi
tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: nil})  // outputs [null]
tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: 0})    // outputs 0
tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, thing{Value: 2})    // outputs 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: I went with `func isNil(value interface{}) bool{return value == nil}`